# How to Call a value inside db query using Fitnesse

Tags: c#, sql, selenium, fitnesse

Her is my code

```
public static string Today{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today.Date;
    return today.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY").Replace("-","/");
}
```

Fitnesse

```
!|className|
|Today|
|>>currentDate|

!|className1|
|sqlQuery|
|select * from data where date='31-Jan-2021'|
```

I need to verify the query daily using the current date, how to add the date value inside the query to run daily

Comment: Is it SQL Server? You could use GETDATE() to get today. It will be with time, 
following would give you only date - (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103));
You could change your query like follows.
select * from data where date= (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [!today](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.MarkupLanguageReference.TodaysDate) symbol to generate a relative date. You can use a format pattern based on [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

For instance `!today (yyyy-MM-dd)`